# Beginner here learning python - why are the '+' signs necessary in this piece of code?

Tags: python, syntax

In this code:

```
print('My name is')
for i in range(5):
    print('Jimmy Five Times (' + str(i) + ')')
```

With this output:

```
My name is
Jimmy Five Times (0)
Jimmy Five Times (1)
Jimmy Five Times (2)
Jimmy Five Times (3)
Jimmy Five Times (4)
```

I understand why the code creates the output, but why are the '+' surrounding the str(I) necessary? I've played around with the code and if I remove the + signs I get a syntax error. Im a beginner so Im sure its something simple but I would really appreciate a simple explanation! :) thanks

Comment: Because those are just string objects and with those `+` you tell Python to "add" them together, which will then call the `__add__` method and concatenate them. (Although the `+` is actually _optional_ when concatenating string _literals_, e.g. `"foo" "bar"`) However, there are many other ways without that `+`, e.g. using different kinds of "format strings".

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you need to use the + sign is that you need to concatenate strings (put one after the other) to get the full string that you want to print. The + operation used on strings concatenates them. If you just write two strings one after the other, Python doesn't understand what you want to do with them. If you want them to be concatenated, you'll have to tell Python to do so using the + operator

Comment: Not quite true. Try typing `"spam" "eggs"` into python.

Comment: Oh, you're right. My mistake, I've just always concatenated strings with the + operator. Weird then, why is it needed there?

Comment: @Fran314 no, `+` concatenates strings. However, if you have a *string literals* the compilers implicitly understands `"some string" "another string"` as one single string. This often helps writing long string literals on multiple lines. This *only* works with string literals, and isn't really the same as concatenation, it's just part of the string literal syntax

Comment: You can only concatenate string *literals* this way. Python reads `"spam" "eggs"` as a single string literal, as if you had written `"spameggs"`, not as two objects that have to be combined later. It got this behavior from C, where it was important for certain kinds of macros. In Python, it's mostly used to break up string literals that are too long for one line, but it's also a source of bugs, which is why Java does require the `+`.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback - I do know that there are more ways to concatenate strings, I am just going based on a book and want to understand this way before moving on. So the + concatenates strings, but what is the purpose of surrounding the str(I) with the + signs? Isn't only one needed? @Fran314

Comment: @Sabrina You do not have to "surround" the `str(i)` with `+` per se, but there are three strings in total, so you need two `+`. If the `str(i)` was the last part, there would only be one `+` required.

Answer (score 2):

When used on strings, `+` concatenates them. The `+` signs are not the only way to do it, but it's not going to work if you just remove them. Python has rules of grammar, like any other language. Sub-expressions can only be combined in ways allowed by the grammar, like with an operator. Juxtaposition has no meaning here, so it's not allowed by the grammar.

I would have used an f-string here:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print(f'Jimmy Five Times ({i})')
...
Jimmy Five Times (0)
Jimmy Five Times (1)
Jimmy Five Times (2)
Jimmy Five Times (3)
Jimmy Five Times (4)
```

Here's another way:

```
for i in range(5):
    print('Jimmy Five Times (', i, ')', sep='')
```

`print()` can print out multiple objects at once. It normally separates them with a space, but you can override that.